# How do I get the sql statement in the DAG to recognize that I'm calling a parameter from Airflow?

Tags: timestamp, airflow, jinja2, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to call the dag runtime from Airflow, however, something in my syntax is off and I need help to correct it.

I've tried this code snippet

```
SQL_INSERT_AIRFLOW_TS = f"INSERT INTO TRASH.TRASH.TEST_UPDATES SELECT NULL, '{{ data_interval_start }}';"
```

and then called it in the DAG. But it just inserts text: '{{ data_interval_start }}', instead of the date/ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for f-string as you are not adding parameter that you defined. `data_interval_start` is Airflow macro.

Simply do:

```
execute_query = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
    task_id="execute_query",
    sql="INSERT INTO TRASH.TRASH.TEST_UPDATES SELECT NULL, '{{ data_interval_start }}';"
)
```

If your real use case is to use both user defined parameters and macros see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74494552/14624409).

Answer (score 1):

When using f-string in this manner you have to escape the curly braces with additional curly braces to inject an Airflow template macro. So, using your example, you'd need:

```
SQL_INSERT_AIRFLOW_TS = f"INSERT INTO TRASH.TRASH.TEST_UPDATES SELECT NULL, '{{{{ data_interval_start }}}}';"
```